# How to scrape Jenkins metrics using Prometheus Operator

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, prometheus-operator

I'm using Kube-prometheus with Prometheus-Operator to monitor my K8s cluster. I've deployed Jenkins on my cluster and want to start to get metrics here using ServiceMonitor.

I've installed the Prometheus plugin which exposes the metrics using `/prometheus` or by `/metrics/API_KEY/metrics`, this works fine if I create a new static job. However, if I want to use ServiceMonitor, it does not work.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1                                                                                                                                                                        
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: jenkins
  name: jenkins
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s 
    port: http
    path: /metrics/y1H6G16T-DhqpHdW9XwHWnP9FWAXMMfy4XnXVnyoIOEV3-gPJZKN284OFUcVkPxL/metrics
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      jenkins: main
```

Comment: documentation states that you should scrape /prometheus path. Did you try that? Also you'd better add "honorLabels: true" to your endpoint config.

Comment: You should also check the port on wich /prometheus is mapped, in jenkins configuration.

Comment: Have you tried to access to /prometheus or /metrics/API_KEY/metrics with a regular curl ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting up on the path with `/prometheus` as I've already mentioned.
@AlexandreCartapanis, sure. I am able to see the metrics if I go to http://jenkins:8080/prometheus and also http://jenkins:8080/metrics/API_KEY/metrics.

Also, worth mention is that If I'm using static_scrape instead of Servicemonitor, it works out

Comment: Have you checked the "target" page of prometheus UI ? It can sometime gives usefull informations for problems resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about ServiceMonitor, but I monitor my Jenkins instance without any problem, using annotations on Jenkins' service :

```
prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
prometheus.io/port: "8080"
prometheus.io/path: "/prometheus"
```

Comment: Beside annotations, have you configured anything else?
I do have those annotations, but still can see Jenkins with 0 active targets inside Prometheus

Comment: Prometheus is deployed with helm using the "prometheus" chart. By default, it include a job that will dynamically detect kubernetes services and try to scrape them when the correct annotations are present. Again, I don't know about prometheus-operator, but check if a job that looks like https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/790457b26dcfdc4ad868ef64115ae0f10f0af0dd/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L1117 is present.

Comment: I’ve ended up replacing the manifests from Kube-Prometheus with the chart, working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using kube-prometheus-stack v12.8.0 (formerly known as the prometheus-operator helm chart).

To make prometheus-operator detect external serviceMonitors (like the one provided by Jenkins), you'll have to configure two things:

1. configure it to scan other namespaces:

   serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector
   matchLabels:
   prometheus: please-scan-this-namespace-too

note: alternatively, you can leave it to {} so that all namespaces are scanned

2. configure it to also select the serviceMonitors detected in these other namespaces:

   serviceMonitorSelector:
   matchLabels:
   release: prometheus-operator

note: even though the documentation states that if you leave serviceMonitorSelector to {}, it will select all serviceMonitors, it does not seem to work.

And finally, you'd still need to add these labels to 1) the namespaces and 2) serviceMonitors that you want prometheus to adopt.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how you've been able to do this?

I'm struggling with the same thing now and can't seem to get my Jenkins to show up on my targets list. It shows up under `Service Discovery` though which is interesting, but not under `targets`